# C#, WMPLib - How to check if the player is playing or not to trigger another process

Tags: c#, audio, mp3, wmplib

I'm new to C#. I want to use only 1 timer to do 2 events with different interval (0.2s and 1s). 0.2s interval is for checking error in system and it cannot stop. 1s interval is for playing sound if an error occurred. So, now I'm using a calculation to skip calling function `checkError()` because if I don't like this the sound won't play properly because of the duration of mp3 file but I would like to use check state of player if it's still playing or not instead of this calculation. For example, it will call `checkError()` again after finished play sound.  What should I do ?

Ps. Sorry for my English :(

```
    WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer wmp = new WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer();
    int count = 0;
    int errorFlag = 0;
    int called = 0;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        timer1.Start();

    }

    private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (errorFlag == 0)
            errorFlag = 1;
    }

    private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (errorFlag == 1)
            errorFlag = 0;
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (errorFlag == 1)
        {
            checkError();
            if (called == 0)
                checkError();
        }

    }

    private void checkError()
    {
        if (called == 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(WMPLib.WMPPlayState.wmppsPlaying);
            called = 1;
            wmp.URL = "C:/Users/ndrs-tnp/Desktop/エラー音.mp3";
            wmp.controls.play();
        }
        count += 1;
        if (count == 5)
        {
            called = 0;
            count = 0;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Look at the events that WindowsMediaPlayer supports and you'll find the answer.

Comment: Could you guide me a little bit ?

Answer (score 0):

read this
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmp/axwmplib-axwindowsmediaplayer-playstate--vb-and-c

```
if (player.playState == WMPLib.WMPPlayState.wmppsPlaying)
{
    playStateLabel.Text = "Windows Media Player is playing!";
}
else
{
    playStateLabel.Text = "Windows Media Player is NOT playing!";
}
```